# load NSDictionary from NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to access a dictionary from an array.

I add the objects to the dictionary like so

```
[_recentDictionary setObject:videoString forKey:@"video"];
[_recentDictionary setObject:imageString forKey:@"image"];
[_recentDictionary setObject:titleString forKey:@"title"];
[_recentDictionary setObject:descriptionString forKey:@"desc"];
```

I then add the dictionary to an array like so

```
for (int i = 0; i<10; ++i)
{
      if (i == 0) {
            [self.recentArray addObject:_recentDictionary];
      }
}
```

and then save the array via a nsuserdefault

```
_savedArray = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[_savedArray setObject:self.recentArray forKey:@"recentArray"];
[_savedArray synchronize];
```

To the call the above in another View

```
NSUserDefaults *savedDefaults = _showListView.savedArray;

NSMutableArray *savedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[savedDefaults objectForKey:@"recentArray"], nil];
```

But I cannot figure out how to access the dictionary in this array.

Comment: I am seeing you are using `_properties`, i would suggest you to use `self.properties`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the one by one array element in a dictionary.

`NSDictionary *dict = [savedArray objectAtIndex:0];`

Then access the elements of dictionary(dict) as per your requirement.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but its returning all the objects still, it appears the the all the objects are at the same index?

Comment: why r u using the for loop for adding the dictionary in an array. Use directly [self.recentArray addObject:_recentDictionary]; and remove for loop.

Comment: this is something else which i will be looking into next. The reason for this is because i wanted to add the dictionary at index 0, then index 1 and so on until index 10. 10 being the max. When 10 is reached i then need to remove object at index 0 and then move all others up an index. each dictionary will contain different objects

Comment: Ok, please check my updated answer. Here retrieve the object of 0th index & store it in dictionary then access the elements of dictionary.

Comment: NSDictionary *recentDection = savedArray[0];
    NSLog(@"recent Dec = %@",recentDection);
would return 2013-01-22 12:44:46.439 Ch - IOS[9512:907] recent Dec = (
        {
        desc = "desc1";
        image = "img1.jpg";
        title = "title1";
        video = "video1";
    }
)
how would i access lets say "title"

Comment: try [recentDection valueForKey:@"title"];

Comment: Once you get the dictionary access the objects using "objectForKey" like [dict objectForKey:@"title"];

Comment: i did try that inoka but it would crash the app saying objectForKey not found. Girish' way works though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the dictionary as

```
recentDictionary = [savedArray objectAtIndex:0];
```